# PyQT5 как узнать индекс позиции виджета, который находится на лейауте?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qpushbutton, qlayout

У меня есть `QFrame` с разметкой `QHBoxLayout`, на котором расположено 6 кнопок `QPushButton`.

Есть ли возможность получить позицию (индекс) конкретной кнопки на `QHBoxLayout`  непосредственно из самой кнопки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

> int QLayout::[**indexOf**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayout.html#indexOf)(const QWidget *`widget`) const
>
> Ищет виджет `widget` в этом макете (не включая дочерние макеты).
>
> Возвращает индекс виджета или -1, если виджет не найден.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.frame_1 = QFrame()
        self.frame_2 = QFrame()
        
        self.layout_main = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.frame_1, 1)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.frame_2, 
            alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        self.label = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout_1 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_1)
        self.layout_1.addWidget(self.label)
        
        self.layout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        for i in range(5):
            btn = QPushButton(
                'Button {}'.format(i),
                clicked=self.on_clicked
            )
            self.layout_2.addWidget(btn)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        btn = self.sender()
        ix = self.layout_2.indexOf(btn)
        text = f'{btn.text()}: индекс = {ix}'
        self.label.setText(text)
        
        new_btn = QPushButton(
            "button {}".format(self.layout_2.count()),
            clicked=self.on_clicked
        )
        self.layout_2.insertWidget(ix+1, new_btn)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(700, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Именно то что мне было нужно

Comment: @ИгорьПлатонов пожалуйста.